# Check hardware performance S5 series

Tags: hardware, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Is there an App that can be used to check the status of the hardware? I want to know the processor and memory performance.

Comment: Any of the top benchmarks on Google Play will do the job and give you results you can compare to other devices: https://play.google.com/store/search?q=benchmark&c=apps&docType=1&sp=CAFiCwoJYmVuY2htYXJregIYAIoBAggB:S:ANO1ljIgzRg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is many methods like **overclock**,

it means you can check the performance or check the Power of Android hardwares.but, this is dangerous for users and then you can check the performance of this hardwares (as `GiantTree` said) ;

**for example :**

The best App ([**AnTuTu Benchmark - Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antutu.ABenchMark&hl=en))

but, excuse us.there is one community for Suggested apps.you need to **ASK** this question on :

```
http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions
```